# .net Start variable function as thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading

How to start a function passed as variable as a thread in .net 3.5?

```
Public Shared Sub starteAlsThread2(addr As Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart)
    Dim pts As New Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(addr)
    lgv_worker = New Threading.Thread(pts)
    lgv_worker.Start(Argumente)
End Sub
```

This way there is a compile error:
"System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart" requires a addressof or lambda expression

Comment: what is `Argumente`?

Comment: `pts` makes no sense, just use `lgv_worker = New Threading.Thread(addr)`.

Comment: @Jodrell: sorry, an object as parameter for the called function

Comment: @Hans Passant: but then I have to pass "new ParameterizedThreadStart(addressof functionname)" for this function? can't this be shortend to "addressof functionname" or similar?

Comment: Sure, no idea why you would ask me instead of your compiler.

Comment: Try `starteAlsThread2(addr As Action)`, then just pass it directly to the thread constructor: `lgv_worker = New Threading.Thread(addr)`.

Comment: @VisualVincent: new Threading.Thread is expecting a ThreadStart or ParameterizedThreadStart as Argument

Comment: You're right, but follow Hans's suggestion. It should work.

Answer (score -1):

Passing variable to a new thread can be done easy using lambda expressions:

```
    Private Sub Test()
        Dim thrd = New Thread(Sub() TestSub("bllablla"))
        thrd.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TestSub(kot As String)
        'Do stuff here
    End Sub
```

Comment: "TestSub" should be the variable part.

Comment: No TestSub is a sub of code with input variables which you can call for execution in a new Thread.